# how to execute multiple columns in query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How to execute multiple columns in query in MongoDB, like this in mysql

```
select * from t where (url, create_time) in ((a,b),(c,d),...)
```

or exist some other manner could achieve the same purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to rephrase the SQL query using the more verbose non tuple form:

```sql
select *
from t
where url = a and create_time = c or url = b and create_time = d or ...
```

Then write Mongo code for this:

```
db.your_collection.find({
    $or : [
        { $and: [ { url : a }, { create_time : c } ] },
        { $and: [ { url : b }, { create_time : d } ] },
        {...}
    ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks! But it's too verbose. It seems bulk.find cannot support this batch query scenario

Comment: @zhuguowei `But it's too verbose` ... keep in mind that most SQL databases don't even support the tuple syntax, and even for those that do, the execution plan of the tuple and verbose versions are probably the same.  The answer I gave you is likely what you will have to do on MongoDB.